# Dynamixel Motor - Clarifying on the use of Position Read

Tags: servomotor, dynamixel

Clarification:
I would like to clarify whether it is ok to use "position read" on the motor position while in velocity mode.

Context:
So I am using the XC330-T288-T motor and basically running a setup with a small plastic gear-like wheel connected to the motor directly. In my setup, the wheel is driving another thin needle-like object - almost like a rack and pinion setup. For running the motor, I am using the motor in Velocity mode at a speed of 0.7 RPM which is like a value of 3 on the range of the motor I have.
Unit             Value Range
0.088 [°]   0 ~ 4,095(1 rotation)

If there is small amount of backlash in the movement of the motor due to the slight resistance in the contact between the needle and wheel, will this also be reflected in the position read value that I obtain? I am using the velocity control mode to set it at a constant speed for about 10-15 seconds.

[image: Image of wheel+needle]

Answer (score 0):

That depends, was there slippage between the load and the pulley that pulls it? If there is, then you will have a false reading.

When the possibility of load slipping occurs (I know it as a non-rigidly coupled load), an external encoder (or another type of sensor, other than that of the motor) is used, which measures the displacement of the load and enters in the control loop.

I don't know the Dynamixel equipment, however some industrial servos have a specific input and parameters to deal with this directly in the firmware (changing the encoder position source from the motor to the external one), which is how I usually deal with it, without the need for complex development, just dealing with the tuning of the system through earnings.

Below is an example of how I deal with this... In this machine the 6 pulleys are connected to a servomotor, there is a risk of the wire slipping, then we put an encoder at the end (in red), which is connected to the driver that controls the servomotor.

[image]